# Flatten the list of list having self reference

Tags: java

Flatten the list of list having self reference.

I have List of List which include a reference to itself and I need to flatten this list. 

Eg. I have list

> A = [ 1, [2,[3]], A, ]

The flattened list would look like this

> A =[1,2,3]

Here is what I have tried (in Java):

```
public static void flattenRecurser(List<Integer> result, List<?> nested) {          
    for (Object item : nested) {
        if (item instanceof List<?> && !freq.containsKey((List<?>) item)) {  
            flattenRecurser(result, (List<?>) item);
        } else if (item instanceof Integer) {
            result.add((Integer) item);
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding nested to map called freq before calling flattenRecurser

```
static Map<List<?>, List<?>> freq = new HashMap<>();

freq.put(nested,nested);
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
flattenRecurser(result, nested);
```

But I get an error when I put nested list in to the freq map.
Finding the hash code for nested object is causing the error. How will I approach this problem in a different way or is there way to find hash for nested object. 

Here is the error I get :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:834)  at
>   java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:540)

I don't have line number 834 or 540 in my code at all

Comment: Could you post the error ? and also your nested object declaration?

Comment: Why are you adding nested to map ? Just compare the reference to the list A itself and if it's same then move on.

Comment: I can't really wrap my head around how the flattened list for `A = [1, [2,[3]], A]` should look. Just `[1,2,3]`, or `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`, or how? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: @piyush121 I am using the map as a way to compare the reference to the list A. If the hash code of the item in list is already seen then I do not flatten that item of the list.

Comment: @tobias_k  I have updated the question with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the lists that have already been added to the result list. YOu can do this with a hash set, but there seems to be a bug (?) with the implementation of `List.hashCode`: While `List.toString` can handle lists containing self-references, `List.hashCode` runs into an infinite recursion. Instead, you could use `System.identityHashCode`.

```
public static List flatten(List flatten, Set<Integer> ignore) {
    List result = new LinkedList();
    ignore.add(System.identityHashCode(flatten));
    for (Object o : flatten) {
        if (o instanceof List) {
            if (! ignore.contains(System.identityHashCode(o))) {
                result.addAll(flatten((List) o, ignore));
            }
        } else {
            result.add(o);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
List C = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
List B = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(2, 3, C, 7));
List A = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, B, 8, 9, C));
C.add(C);
B.add(B);
A.add(A);

System.out.println(A);
System.out.println(flatten(A, new HashSet<>()));
```

Output:

```
[1, [2, 3, [4, 5, 6, (this Collection)], 7, (this Collection)], 8, 9, [4, 5, 6, (this Collection)], (this Collection)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that there *can* be clashes with this approach, i.e. two different lists having the same identity hashcode. In this case, one of the lists would not be added to the result. Alternatively, you can loop the entire `ignore` set and compare each element to the current list with `==`.

Comment: Nice answer. Will look how system.identityHashcode works. Yes, I think this is an issue not just with list but with any data structure having self reference.

Comment: Just noted that `List.toString` has a similar issue when two lists are "tangled", i.e. `a = [b]` and `b = [a]`, producing a StackOverflow error. Python can handle this (and will print just `[[[...]]]`)

Answer (score 0):

You are having an endless recursion. If item == nested -> do nothing.